# Grabbing data from google places api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I need to grab all business locations in the city of miami from google places.  The trouble is they limit you to 60 results per request. Is there anyway to get around this? I thought about limiting the search down more and doing more requests but i'm kind of stuck there with how to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Read the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).  `(c) No Mass Downloads or Bulk Feeds of Content.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) is the documentation of Google Places API for searching places. As you can read in the bottom "The maximum number of results that can be returned is 60.".

So you have to make more than one request to get all results.

As you say you want only the location of the business, so i would use Radar Search which allows you to search for up to 200 places at once, but with less detail (location is included in the response) than is typically returned from a Text Search or Nearby Search request.

So you have to make some calls in this format:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=25.789097,-80.204044&radius=5000&types=movie_theater&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

Where you can read more about parameter types [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types). Also remember to use your own api key

This call will return up to 200 places, with their location, in a cirlce with radius 5000 meters around the location( here 25.789097,-80.204044).

So the first call should be with location=25.789097,-80.204044(Miami center) and radius lets say 500 meters.

The second call should be with location a point outside the first circle and in a way that this cirlce does not overlap the previous one and radius 500 meters.

And you continue this way.

You have to set some circles that dont overlap each other and they cover the desired area you want in Miami.

If you want to get all the information about the google place you should use this call:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=25.789097,-80.204044&radius=500&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

which returns up to 20 results though, in the same way i explained before.